# Runat error in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, runtime-error

i have a login form code with master page but i seen an error when i run it on browser. I cannot understand the error, how can i remove it? Error picture is also attached.
Please anyone can help me?

My code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Login" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table align="center">

<b>Login Form</b>

<tr>
<td>
Username:
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUser" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password:
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPWD" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPWD" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPWD" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Master page code is :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:Teal;">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center">
        <h1>My Test WebSite</h1>
        <div align = "left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblpageName" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="3"
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1em" ForeColor="#284E98" Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticSubMenuIndent="20px" Height="25px" Width="550px">
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="3px" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="HOME" Value="HOME" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="ABOUT" Value="ABOUT" NavigateUrl="~/about.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="CONTACT" Value="CONTACT" NavigateUrl="~/contact.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Change.aspx" Text="CHANGE" Value="CHANGE"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="LOGIN" Value="Login" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Menu>

        </div>
        <!-- Here we have content place holder where all content pages will render their controls   -->
        <hr />
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:contentplaceholder>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error picture is:
[image]

Comment: On your master page you already have included a head section so you should not be doing it in login.aspx....if you want to have separate head section for each page then in master page use placeholder

Comment: @Sam so u mean i remove this line ? <head id="Head1" runat="server">

Comment: yes remove the head section from login.aspx or use content place holder in masterpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `MasterPage` which also has a `Head` tag, that's why you get this error. So remove it from your content page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>
<table align="center">
<b>Login Form</b>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `runat="server"` from your content page.

keep it as `<head>.....</head>`

Since in your master page you have head tag with `runat=server` (might have) , you should remove it from content page.

**EDIT:**

Remove Following:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
```

Comment: when i remove runat="server" then it shows another error: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib if header is not required there (seems to be not required) ,, remove it

Comment: m really sorry i cannot understand. can u edit my code for me please.

Comment: it is not working it shows another error  A page can have only one server-side Form tag.